# Odoo 16 Calendar and events connection

Tags: python, module, odoo-16

So I want to have a calendar on my events pages so that the users can click on the day that they want and see the events for that day. but I can't do it I am looking for alternatives or solutions.

I tried searching for modules like calendar. event and the others but I couldn’t find them on the odoo store for 16. I also tried to search about adding an event to the main calendar and somehow bringing that to the event page but I can't find a solution. any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This addon from Webkul should provide what you're looking for:
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/16.0/calendar_events/

I'm not thrilled with the look of the calendar, but maybe that can be changed with some better CSS styling.